# Cannot find a group of native methods for android, specifically in ExifInterface.java

Tags: java, android, native-code

I have seen other links out there for viewing native code for android however I cannot seem to find the native code in the ExifInterface.java file. Does anyone have a good resource for viewing the native code?

These are the methods I am referring to specifically:

```
private native boolean appendThumbnailNative(String fileName, String thumbnailFileName);

private native void saveAttributesNative(String fileName, String compressedAttributes);

private native String getAttributesNative(String fileName);

private native void commitChangesNative(String fileName);

private native byte[] getThumbnailNative(String fileName);

private native long[] getThumbnailRangeNative(String fileName);
```

Comment: Native code is written in C, so naturally would not appear in java files...

Comment: @LenaBru I should clarify, I'm not looking for it inside the .java, I just want to know if the c files can be found anywhere.